# Como extrair as informações de um arquivo 'cnab' usando python?

Tags: python, arquivo

Preciso extrair as informações de um arquivo cnab (que é um arquivo de texto), conseguir ler o arquivo usando `python.read` porém não sei como progredir.

Conteudo do arquivo:

```
39900000         2957742120001329999999999          00009900000000000990GRUPO NEXXERA                 HSBC                          NEXXERA   107062017095759000000102001600                                                                    
39900011C2001010 2957742120001329999999999          00009900000000000990GRUPO NEXXERA                                                         Rua Madalena Barbi            181                 Centro-Florianopolis88015190SC                  
3990001300001A00000039900001900000000001090EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 1          0000000001          07062017BRL000000000000000000000000000010                    00000000000000000000000                                                    0          
3990001300002A00070039900002900000000002090EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 2          0000000002          07062017BRL000000000000000000000000020020                    00000000000000000000000                                                    0          
3990001300003A00001839900003900000000003090EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 3          0000000003          07062017BRL000000000000000000000003030030                    00000000000000000000000                                                    0          
39900015         000005000000000003050060000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                               
39999999         000001000007000000
```

codigo:

```
 def abre_aquivo():

    conteudo = open("modelo_arquivo.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")

    conteudo_formatado = conteudo.read()
    # print(type(conteudo_formatado))
    x = conteudo_formatado.split()
    print(x)

    conteudo.close()

abre_aquivo()
```

Relatorio esperado:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nome da Empresa | Numero de Inscricao da Empresa | Nome do Banco | Nome da Rua        | Numero do Local | Nome da Cidade       | CEP       | Sigla do Estado
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPRESA XX      | 00.000.000/0000-00             | XXX           | Rua Madalena Barbi | 181             | Centro-Florianopolis | 00000-000 | SC
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nome do Favorecido   | Data de Pagamento | Valor do Pagamento | Numero do Documento Atribuido pela Empresa | Forma de Lancamento
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 1 | 07/06/2017        | R$ 0,10            | 0000000001                                 | Credito em Conta Corrente
EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 2 | 07/06/2017        | R$ 200,20          | 0000000002                                 | Credito em Conta Corrente
EMPRESA FORNECEDOR 3 | 07/06/2017        | R$ 30.300,30       | 0000000003                                 | Credito em Conta Corrente
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Teria algum trecho de código para análise ou logs/erros para serem verificados bem como o arquivo 'cnab'?

Comment: Coloquei o conteúdo do arquivo e o código que tenho na pergunta.

Comment: Quais são as informações que precisa extrair? Como é o formato deste arquivo? São colunas ou algo assim?

Comment: O [site da FEBRABAN](https://portal.febraban.org.br/pagina/3053/33/pt-br/layout-240) tem estes padrões definidos, você chegou a ler?

Comment: Sim, li a documentação do site, mas não ajudou na questão da extração.

Comment: Não entendi como não ajudou... São nestes arquivos que especificam a estrutura dos arquivos `.cnab`. Por exemplo: os 3 primeiros dígitos são o código FEBRABAN do banco, que no seu caso é `399`, que é o HSBC. O que está impedindo você de extrair as informações? Desconhecer a estrutura do arquivo ou não saber como fazer isso em Python?

Comment: É a estrutura do arquivo que continua confusa, fazer o parse no python eu sei tranquilo. Pelo jeito preciso ler mais da documentação.

Answer (score 3):

É um tipo de arquivo com tamanhos de campos fixos - você lê uma linha, e usa a sintaxe de fatias do Python para extrair o valor de cada campo  -

Por exmeplo, para a linha:

```
39900000         2957742120001329999999999          00009900000000000990GRUPO NEXXERA                 HSBC                          NEXXERA   107062017095759000000102001600
```

Se essa linha estiver na variável "row" - podemos ver, contando nela, ou, de preferencia na especificação do arquivo, que os limites dos campos são nas colunas

17, 52, 72, 102, 132, 142

**atualização, março 2020**

Quando escrevi a resposta original, devia estar com pouco tempo, e mandei o código de uma boa alternativa pra isso, mas sem explica o que estava fazendo (código abaixo, mantido da resposta original).

No entanto é importante *entender* o que se está fazendo. A forma mais simples de acessar esses valores é, lógico, usar a sintaxe de "fatia" do Python para pegar substrings. Então, se pegar as linhas de dados, sabendo-se dos índices acima, é só fazer, em código Python normal, dentro de qualquer função:

```py
campo1 = linha[0:17]
campo2 = linha[17:52]
campo3 = linha[52:72]
...
```

Note que a decisão de design de Python de intervalos serem fechados no inicio e abertos no final (isso é, incluem o primeiro elemento, mas param antes do último elemento de uma fatia), ajuda MUITO - o campo1 vai até imediatamente *antes* do caractere na posição 17)

Agora, fazer assim, principalmente como vamos ter vários layouts diferentes, fica estranho - e ter que passar essas variáveis para um dicionário, ou criar um objeto depois, ficaria repetitivo - mas não estaria errado - seria um código direto e de fácil entendimento.

A abordagem que usei usa mecanismos avançados do Python, que permitem que se crie uma "classe especializada para funcionar como atributos de outro objeto" (esse tipo de classe se chama "Descriptor") - e ela pode usar código para gerar esses atributos, em vez de serem dados. E aí, eu escrevo código justamente para pegar os dados nas posições específicas da string contendo a linha - exatamente como acima, mas disparado automaticamente pelo Python quando alguém quiser acessar  `meuobjeto.campo1`. O código para isso que é o da resposta original

**fim da atualização**

O ideal é criar uma família de classes - isso é, uma classe "base" e uma classe filha representando cada tipo de objeto que vai estar no arquivo, de forma que você possa especificar os campos e seus delimitadores de forma bem legível nessas classes filhas, e na classe base ponha um método que, dado o registro, extrai as informações dos locais corretos.

Dá até pra fazer com "descriptors" e quardas os dados como texto bruto dentro do Python, e o código `__get__` do descriptor já vai no campo certo.

Claro que aí você vai ter objetos aninhados - as linhas de indices 2, 3 e 4 do exemplo são transações, e o melhor que você faz é criar uma classe separada para informações das mesmas (e no objeto pai, coloca uma "lista de transações" como atributo. )  A logica pra isso fica um pouco mais legal, mas não tenho como fazer na resposta.

Entao, fazendo só a primeira linha:

```py
class Campo:
    def __init__(self, inicio, final):
        self.inicio = inicio
        self.final = final

    def __set_name__(self, owner, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        return instance.dados_brutos[self.inicio: self.final]

class Base:
    def __init__(self, dados):
        self.dados_brutos = dados

    def __repr__(self):
        campos = []
        for name, obj in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(obj, Campo):
                campos.append((name, getattr(self, name)))
        return "\n".join(f"{campo}:{conteudo}" for campo, conteudo in campos)

class CNAB_LINHA1(Base):
    campo1 = Campo(0, 17)
    campo2 = Campo(17, 52)
    campo3 = Campo(72, 102)
    campo4 = Campo(102, 132)
    campo5 = Campo(123, 142)
    campo6 = Campo(142, None)
```

E no terminal:

```py
In [59]: a = """39900000         2957742120001329999999999          00009900000000000990GRUPO NEXXERA                 HSBC         
    ...:                  NEXXERA   107062017095759000000102001600"""                                                              

In [60]: b = CNAB_LINHA1(a)                                                                                                        

In [61]: print(b)                                                                                                                  
campo1:39900000         
campo2:2957742120001329999999999          
campo3:GRUPO NEXXERA                 
campo4:HSBC                          
campo5:         NEXXERA   
campo6:107062017095759000000102001600
```

Comment: Vamos supor que eu desejaria alterar o valor do `campo3` e fazer com que esse valor seja refletido nos `dados_brutos` que representa o CNAB, eu implementaria um `__set__` na classe `Campo` ou seria de outra forma? A intenção é deixar o algoritmo funcionando para operação de leitura e escrita.

Comment: Sim - nesse caso, se vocë puser um método `__set__` na classe "Campo" que respeite os mesmos limites de bytes, e faça o padding adequado com espaços em branco ou 0s, você poderia fazer funcionar a escrita. O ideal é escrever os dados em um novo arquivo - e ao fim da escrita apagar o antigo e renomear o arquivo novo pra ficar no lugar daquele - mas seria possível até a escrita "inplace", nesse caso. (ao contrário do que possa ser o "feeling", isso não seria mais eficiente nos computadores modernos, no entanto)