# Modificando um arquivo em Python sem perder o conteúdo atual

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, arquivo

Essa dúvida é uma continuação desta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461155/substituir-trecho-de-uma-string-entre-2-%c3%adndices/461172#461172).

Eu tenho um arquivo TXT bem grande (cerca de 6GB), sendo cada linha com 1.300 caracteres, e eu estou manipulando essas linhas, como exemplo, vou usar essas três linhas aqui (o site está comendo os espaços em branco, mas as linhas possuem o mesmo layout):

```
123456 BANANA 00 SP
123457 MACA   01 RJ
123458 PERA   02 MG
```

O que eu preciso é caso a linha contenha a palavra "BANANA" na posição 8:14, ele altere o "00" da posição 16:17 para "22".

Para isso, estou implementando algo como:

```
arquivo = open('testando.txt', 'r') #abre o arquivo
for linha in arquivo:
    codigo = str(linha[8:14])
    
    if codigo == 'BANANA':
       print("ACHOU, CODIGO: " + codigo)
       encontrado = True
    else:
       print("NÃO ACHOU, CÓDIGO: " + codigo)
       encontrado = False

    if encontrado:
        new_line = linha[:16] + "22" + linha[17:] #como python utiliza string imutáveis, estou apenas remontando ela
        print(new_line)
        linha = linha.replace(linha, new_line) #substituo a linha antiga pela nova, com a nova informacao
        arquivo = open('testando.txt','w')
        arquivo.write(linha) #adiciono minha nova linha no arquivo
        
    print(linha)
        
arquivo.close()
```

O problema que estou encontrando é que ele está salvando somente a linha que eu alterei e deletando todo o resto do arquivo. Imaginei que eu percorrendo linha a linha, ele fosse alterar somente a linha daquele index, porém ele está substituindo o arquivo completo.

PS: ja tentei colocar o método `write` depois do `if` e também já tentei o `writelines`.

Sabem de alguma forma de manter o arquivo intacto e alterar somente a parte desejada?

Comment: Coloque o `arquivo.write(linha)` fora do `if`. Creio que você não está tratando adequadamente a abertura e fechamento de seu arquivo. Estude um pouco mais.

Comment: Você abre o arquivo em modo read no início e depois modifica a variável arquivo abrindo ele de novo em modo write a cada iteração do for?

Comment: se eu coloco o write fora do IF e se eu tiver +1 BANANA, ele deleta um e mantém o outro, vamos supor que eu altere o PERA para BANANA também... no final fica somente a PERA e a MAÇÃ no arquivo....

Comment: @GuilhermeBrügger basicamente isso, a cada linha eu abro e altero o arquivo... impossível manter em memoria com o readlines pq é um arquivo de 6GB

Comment: Você não deve ler uma linha, alterar o seu valor e depois tentar reescrever essa linha no mesmo arquivo. Isso não funciona. Abra o arquivo, leia e altere cada linha e salve em um novo arquivo. Assim o original fica mantido se o programa terminar no meio.

Comment: Sim, vou implementar isso futuramente, até para garantir que o arquivo não corrompa. Mas antes preciso modificar as linhas que eu preciso sem deletar o resto do conteúdo... Ou você acha que a solução talvez seria ir copiando linha a linha para um novo file?

Comment: Você não tem que deletar o resto das linhas. Se a linha não tiver o valor que vc procura, vc simplesmente escreve ela sem modificação no novo arquivo. Se tiver, vc modifica e escreve a nova linha. Ou isso ou coloca tudo na memória. Ainda assim, conceitualmente não há diferença. A string de 6GB na memória seria como o novo arquivo, mas em um suporte de memória mais eficiente.

Comment: Resposya aceita, e disucussões à parte, voce sabe que um arquivo texto é uma péssima opção pra manter um conjunto de dados que você precisa alterar, pior ainda desse tamanho, não é?
Como as linhas tem tamanho fixo em bytes, isso é _possível_ - senão nem seria - não quer dizer que seja _desejável_. dependendo da sua tarefa, pode valer muito (mas muito) a pena colocar seus dados numa base sqlite - e se tiver algum sistema legado que precise desse formato específico, gerar o arquivo final de saída quando for a hora.

Comment: Em Python é quase trivial criar uma classe que representa uma linha no seu arquivo - se estiver muito afim, um pouco mais de código poderia criar índices para alguns campos, e você poderia ter algo rápido de acesso randômico - mesmo nesse formato de arquivo aí

Comment: Confira a minha resposta aqui, para um arquivo que usa estrutura de dados de texto, em linhas de tamanho fixo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399778/como-extrair-as-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-um-arquivo-cnab-usando-python/400033#400033

Comment: @jsbueno isso é um sistema legado da empresa... concordo com tudo que disse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, chamar [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) em `str(linha[8:14])` é redundante e desnecessário, pois `linha[8:14]` já retorna uma string. Além disso, no arquivo de exemplo que você informou, este trecho corresponde a "ANANA " (mas vamos assumir que no arquivo original os índices sejam esses mesmo, é um pequeno ajuste que não interfere no restante).

Outro ponto é que você está lendo do arquivo ao mesmo tempo em que escreve nele. Se der algum erro no meio do caminho, o arquivo ficará corrompido, então o ideal é você primeiro escrever tudo em outro arquivo temporário, e só no final, se tudo der certo, mover o arquivo temporário para o original.

E [como eu já disse em sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/461168/112052), essa variável `encontrado` é desnecessária. Se quer fazer algo caso a string seja "BANANA", faça tudo dentro do primeiro `if`:

```
import shutil, tempfile

# lê do arquivo e escreve em outro arquivo temporário
with open('testando.txt', 'r') as arquivo, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
    for linha in arquivo:
        codigo = linha[8:14]
        
        if codigo == 'BANANA':
           print("ACHOU, CODIGO: " + codigo)
           linha = linha[:16] + "22" + linha[17:] # remontar a linha
        else:
           print("NÃO ACHOU, CÓDIGO: " + codigo)

        out.write(linha) # escreve no arquivo temporário

# move o arquivo temporário para o original
shutil.move(out.name, 'testando.txt')
```

Repare que o `write` fica fora do `if`, já que é algo que deve ser feito sempre. A única coisa que muda é que a `linha` é modificada caso caia no `if`. Se o código não for "BANANA", a linha é escrita sem modificação.

Usei [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) para abrir os arquivos, pois isso garante que eles serão fechados ao final (mesmo em caso de erro, o que não acontece quando você chama [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) diretamente - a não ser que ele esteja um bloco [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)).

Eu também uso o [módulo `tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) para criar o arquivo temporário e [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) para renomear o arquivo ao final.

Veja também que o `replace` que você fazia não é necessário, dá para atribuir a remontagem na própria variável `linha`.

Comment: É isso. A diferença é que essa resposta endereçou tudo o que está errado no código e os meus comentários só trataram da pergunta principal.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Realmente os indices estao diferentes aqui, mas faz sentido aqui no meu arquivo de testes. Eu só estou com um problema, agora fugindo um pouco do meu exemplo... vamos supor que BANANA esteja na linha 2 e o "00" esteja na linha 1, ou seja, eu primeiro verifico na linha de baixo e depois preciso "subir" para outra linha p/ fazer a alteração... qual a melhor forma de fazer isso uma vez que o for do python nao tem um index?

Comment: @LuizGTVSilva Aí me parece o caso de fazer outra pergunta (mas pesquise no site antes, já deve ter algum exemplo). A princípio vc tem que guardar a linha anterior também, mas como eu já disse, pesquise que já deve ter algo assim, e se não tiver, faça outra pergunta - não estou dizendo isso por mal, é só pra manter o site organizado: uma pergunta por problema específico :-) Não esqueça de aceitar esta resposta (caso ela tenha resolvido, claro)

Comment: Beleza, valeu! Vou procurar e qualquer coisa faço outra.

Comment: não é por nada - mas gravar tudo em outro arquivo e renomear no final - é legal pra arquivo até 10, 20MB - com 6GB - uma operação que seria de sub-milisegundos pode levar horas. Como as linhas tem tamanho fixo, dá sim pra tratar cada linha como um registro de comprimento 1300 bytes, e trabalhar "inplace" - os sistemas operacionais ajudam.

Comment: Claro que não é a melhor opção - o melhor mesmo seria escrever uma class e algumas 4 ou 5 funções auxiliares para ter um "mini orm" e jogar esse cara num sqlite - ou já usar um sqlalchemy.

Comment: @jsbueno Concordo plenamente, e faço um *mea culpa*: eu ia editar a resposta falando sobre isso, mas no fim fiquei sem tempo. Só consegui voltar agora pra editá-la, mas como eu sei que não vou conseguir sugerir nada melhor que a sua resposta, acho que vou deixar assim mesmo :-) De qualquer forma, agradeço pelos comentários 

Comment: E se alguém mais chegar aqui - é importante ter em mente que se não forem _todas_as_linhas_ do mesmo tamanho (essa estrutura de arquivos é um legado de como os sistemas trabalhavam em mainframes) - então, sim, o único jeito de fazer é esse aí: criar um outro arquivo e mudar só as linhas que interessam.

Answer (score 2):

Como a resposta mais eficiente nesse caso é substancialmente diferente da resposta aceita, vou escrever um pouco.
Já foi comentado nos comentários que essa não seria nem de longe a estrutua adequada para uma massa de dados desse tamanho - ainda mais uma que precise ser alterada.

Como as linhas tem tamanho *fixo* isso é possível.
Mas você deve abrir o arquivo no modo especial "rb+" - se tentar abrir no modo "w", o sistema apaga o arquivo todo mesmo - e aí, tomar algum cuidado para gravar cada linha de volta no lugar em que está.

## Acessando os registros de forma estruturada:

Primeiro, no entanto, vamos ver como acessar os dados *dentro* de cada linha de forma que seja possível manter o sistema, sem ter que, a cada modificação, ter que ficar contando nos dedos em qual coluna vai cada campo, e colocar isso num if.

Agora, querer pra fazer isso brincando de índices dentro de cada linha mbutidos em vários comandos "if" no caminho vai deixar a coisa mais difícil - esse é um caso típico em que pode se usar as capacidades do Python de customizar acesso a atributos em uma classe para criar algo *bem* legal: uma classe em que você acessa e modifica cada coluna pelo nome do campo, e internamente ela mantem os dados numa string única, que pode ser escrita no arquivo original ou impressa.

A resposta em [Como extrair as informações de um arquivo 'cnab' usando python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399778/como-extrair-as-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-um-arquivo-cnab-usando-python/400033#400033)
cobre como criar ma classe dessas -as classes "Campo" e "Base" do jeito que estão lá criam um objeto que é um "descritor" (classe Campo): ele personaliza o acesso aos dados em atributos = e a classe "Base" tem o restante da maquinaria para permitir o acesso aos campos:

```py
class Campo:
    def __init__(self, inicio, final):
        self.inicio = inicio
        self.final = final

    def __set_name__(self, owner, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        return instance.dados_brutos[self.inicio: self.final]

class Base:
    def __init__(self, dados):
        self.dados_brutos = dados

    def __repr__(self):
        campos = []
        for name, obj in self.__class__.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(obj, Campo):
                campos.append((name, getattr(self, name)))
        return "\n".join(f"{campo}:{conteudo}" for campo, conteudo in campos)
```

com esse trecho de menos de 25 linhas, é possível agora representar as linhas no seu arquivo como uma classe específica:

```py
class Frutas(Base):
    codigo = Campo(0, 6)
    nome = Campo(7, 13)
    valor = Campo(14, 16)
    uf = Campo(17, 19)
```

Olha só - eu colo exatamente o código acima, mais o trecho que você passou como exemplo, numa sessão interativa do Python e veja como isso funciona:

```
    ...: exemplo = """\ 
    ...: 123456 BANANA 00 SP 
    ...: 123457 MACA   01 RJ 
    ...: 123458 PERA   02 MG""" 
    ...:      
    ...: class Frutas(Base): 
    ...:     codigo = Campo(0, 6) 
    ...:     nome = Campo(7, 13) 
    ...:     valor = Campo(14, 16) 
    ...:     uf = Campo(17, 19) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [34]: x = [Frutas(linha) for linha in exemplo.split("\n")]                                                                                                                                                                  

In [35]: x[0].nome                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[35]: 'BANANA'

In [36]: x[0].valor = "23"                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [37]: x[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[37]: 
codigo:123456
nome:BANANA
valor:23
uf:SP

In [38]: x[0].dados_brutos                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[38]: '123456 BANANA 00 SP'
```

## Manipulando as linhas do arquivo como registros, com acesso randômico

Agora, depois que uma linha for lida, já temos como trabalhar com ela - a ideia de ter uma classe pra representar um arquivo desses aberto, e poder aí usar essa classe pra ler ou escrever uma linha por vez, sem o código que faz isso precisar de preocupar com *onde* ou *como* os dados estão guardados pode ser a mais interessante.
(Daí, se amanhã você troca  o armazenamento dos dados para outro lugar, seja uma base SQL, NoSQL, etc... o código que usa os dados nem precisa *saber* disso )

```py
from pathlib import Path

class MapeadorTxt:
    def __init__(self, caminho_arquivo, classe_dados, comprimento_linha, codificacao="ASCII"):
        self.caminho = Path(caminho_arquivo)
        self.classe = classe_dados
        self.comp = comprimento_linha
        self.codificacao = codificacao
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.arquivo = open(self.caminho, "rb+")
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        self.arquivo.close()
        self.arquivo = None
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        self.arquivo.seek(index * self.comp)
        return self.classe(self.arquivo.read(self.comp).decode(self.codificacao))
    
    def __setitem__(self, index, valor):
       self.arquivo.seek(index * self.comp)
       v = valor.dados_brutos.rstrip("\n").ljust(self.comp - 1) + "\n"
       self.arquivo.write(v.encode(self.codificacao))
       
    def __len__(self):
        return self.caminho.stat().st_size // self.comp
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Mapeador do arquivo {self.caminho} para a classe {self.classe.__name__}, com {len(self)} registros"
```

E com essa classe é possível fazer o que você propõe na pergunta, usando a classe acima num bloco "with" -e usamos a função `enumerate` no `for` para ter, além do registro, o índice também - (fica na variável`i`) e aí, se quiser acessar o registro na linha de cima, é só usar `m[i - 1]`, por exemplo.

Aqui funcionando pra trocar o código da banana pra "42":

```py
In [57]: m = MapeadorTxt("exemplo.txt", Frutas, 19)                                                                                                           

In [58]: with m: 
    ...:     for i, fruta in enumerate(m): 
    ...:         if fruta.nome.strip() == "BANANA": 
    ...:             fruta.valor = "42" 
    ...:             m[i] = fruta 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                      

In [59]: cat exemplo.txt                                                                                                                                      
123456 BANANA 42 SP
123457 MACA   01 RJ
123458 PERA   02 MG
```

Esse código acima não é perfeito - em particular, o "campo" deveria lidar com encoding e decoding de texto, e deixar os valores internos em bytes, ou em um "bytearray".

E, claro, isso não resolve o problema de tempo de acesso - você continua tendo 500 milhões de registros, que numa comparação dessas tem que ser lidos um a um  - jogue numa base SQL, e pode fazer buscas por datas, etc...

Comment: Aprendi bastante com seu comentário, muito obrigado mesmo! Mas não vou aplicar essa solução, é para algo pontual da empresa que nunca mais vou utilizar! Mas na sua explicação tem diversos conceitos que me foi muito útil! Obrigado

Eu vou fazer uma outra pergunta referente a como "voltar" um indice após verificar o indice de baixo... se puder ajudar também, agradeço :)

Comment: sim- a segund part da resposta mostra como fazer acesso randomico no arquivo - 

se forem dados valiosos - esse código todo tem menos de 100 linhas - mesmo pra um caso único, eu recomendaria - qual a chance de voce errar um limite de um campo em um "if" com com registros de 1300 bytes? 0? Qual o prejuizo de em alguma coluna de valor todos os valores aparecerem divididos por 10?