# Consultando index anterior em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, arquivo

Essa pergunta é uma continuação desta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461358/modificando-um-arquivo-em-python-sem-perder-o-conte%c3%bado-atual?noredirect=1#comment875951_461358)

Como já informado anteriormente, tenho um script que faz uma busca em um txt por uma palavra-chave (MAÇÃ) e caso dê **true**, ele altera uma outra parte ("00" ou "01" ou "02") desse mesmo TXT, para exemplificar, vou seguir com essas três linhas:

**123456 BANANA 00 SP

123457 MACA   01 RJ

123458 PERA   02 MG**

Acontece que essas três linhas fazem parte de um mesmo "cabeçalho".

O código que já está fazendo isso é este (o numero das posições não reflete com a realidade, é somente um exemplo, mas no arquivo real elas possuem um layout):

```
import shutil, tempfile

# lê do arquivo e escreve em outro arquivo temporário
with open('teste.txt', 'r') as arquivo, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
    for linha in arquivo:
        codigo = linha[07:14] #PESQUISA POR MAÇÃ
        
        if codigo == 'MACA':
           print("ACHOU, CODIGO: " + codigo)
           linha = linha[:14] + "22" + linha[16:] # remontar a linha com a alteração
        else:
           print("NÃO ACHOU, CÓDIGO: " + codigo)

        out.write(linha) # escreve no arquivo temporário

# move o arquivo temporário para o original
shutil.move(out.name, 'teste.txt')
```

Porém há um problema de lógica nesta solução, pois a minha realidade é que se na **segunda linha** eu encontrar a "MAÇÃ", eu não vou alterar a mesma linha, e sim a **linha de cima**, que pertence a "BANANA" e que meu código já passou. Portanto o resultado que eu espero caso o script finalize é:

**123456 BANANA 22 SP

123457 MACA   01 RJ

123458 PERA   02 MG**

**UPDATE**

A solução que eu segui então foi: criar uma lista e ir adicionando minhas linhas nela, para eu poder voltar uma posição caso necessário, e ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
import shutil, tempfile
saida = []
# lê do arquivo e escreve em outro arquivo temporário
with open('teste.txt', 'r') as arquivo, \
 tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
  for i,linha in enumerate(arquivo):
  saida.append(linha)
  saidaLinha = saida[i]
  codigo = linha[07:14]
  if codigo == 'MACA':
   print("ACHOU, CODIGO: " + codigo)
   saidaLinha = saida[i-1][:14] + "22" + saida[i-1][16:]
   out.write(saidaLinha)
   print('linha alterada: '+saidaLinha)
 else:
 print("NÃO ACHOU, CÓDIGO: " + codigo)
out.write(linha)
# move o arquivo temporário para o original
shutil.move(out.name, 'teste.txt')
```

Porém, meu output está repetindo a primeira linha sem alteração sempre, por exemplo assim:

123456 BANANA 01 SP
123456 BANANA 22 SP
123457 MACA 01 RJ
123458 PERA 02 MG

Alguém sabe como consertar essa parte?

Comment: Então cara, primeiro é preciso que você conserte a indentação do seu código. No Python quando a indentação está errada, coisas estranhas acontecem. Além disso, note que você continua chamando `out.write` em todas as iterações. Dessa forma, não adianta nada a lista `saida`, pois no final você não está escrevendo ela. Não escreva no arquivo de saída dentro do laço principal. Primeiro você escreve em `saida`, e depois do laço principal você escreve todo o conteúdo de `saida` no seu arquivo.

Comment: Como indentar corretamente: https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Conceitos_b%C3%A1sicos/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo você armazenar todas as saídas que tu for escrever em uma lista de strings. Aí, quando precisar modificar o anterior, basta modificar na lista. No final você escreve o conteúdo da lista todo. A função `enumerate` também ajuda, pois com ela você pode percorrer um iterável com referência tanto para o índice quanto para seus valores.

```
import shutil, tempfile
out = []

# lê do arquivo e escreve em outro arquivo temporário
with open('teste.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    for i, linha in enumerate(arquivo):
        codigo = linha[07:14] #PESQUISA POR MAÇÃ
        
        if codigo == 'MACA':
           print("ACHOU, CODIGO: " + codigo)
           linha = linha[:14] + "22" + linha[16:] # remontar a linha com a alteração
        else:
           print("NÃO ACHOU, CÓDIGO: " + codigo)

        out.append(linha)

with open('teste.txt', 'w') as saida:
    saida.writelines(out)
```

Se alguma coisa não ficou clara o suficiente, por favor comente, tentarei melhorar.

Comment: Desculpa, eu não entendi muito bem a que eu atribuiria **saida[i - 1]**... eu entendo que estou criando uma lista onde cada linha será um indice... mas essa parte eu fiquei confuso

Comment: Então cara, eu dei uma editada, acredito que ficou mais claro agora. Peguei seu código e mexi pouca coisa, a diferença é que agora `out` é uma lista de strings. No final, tu vai pegar essa lista de strings e escrever no teu arquivo.

Como agora você tem um indexador `i`, quando quiser olhar a linha anterior basta acessar `out[i - 1]` e fazer as modificações necessárias. Se ainda não estiver claro o suficiente não hesite em perguntar, valeu!!

Comment: Esse código ta dando erro Allan! Mas eu entendi o que você quis dizer, ainda fico um pouco confuso em como vou chamar o **out[i - 1]**, seria algo como **linha = out[i - 1]**?

Comment: Boa solução. O código contêm erros, um deles é variável out que é reatribuída ao NamedTemporaryFile.

Comment: Removi a reatribuição, não tinha visto isso. Valeu Pablo. Então Luiz, pra acessar o conteúdo da linha anterior à que você está, basta fazer `out[i - 1]` mesmo. Se você quiser fazer um experimento pode printar `linha` e `out[i - 1]` a cada iteração, certamente vai lhe ajudar a entender melhor como o laço está funcionando.

Comment: Allan, eu consegui avançar, mas meu código está repetindo a primeira linha, voce consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Como assim repetindo a linha? Edita seu post com o novo código e descreve em detalhes o comportamento que você está obtendo.