# Como somar intervalos específicos de várias linhas?

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo com várias linhas e desejo somar determinado intervalo considerando todas as linhas. Para simplificar, tomei como exemplo:

```
AAA0000011111000090011
BBB0000011111000080011
CCC0000011111000070011
```

São várias linhas a mais e campos também, mas conheço o intervalo que desejo somar. Caso queira somar "00009", "00008" e "00007" que iniciam na posição 14 e terminam na posição 18 qual é a forma mais eficiente? Também desejo somar "0011", "0011" e "0011". Quero escrever em um novo arquivo os campos.

O resultado seria um novo arquivo com as somas:

```
24
33
```

Pensei da seguinte maneira:

```
file_name = teste.GS3
arquivo = open(file_name, "r")
TOTAL_CHARGEABLE_UNITS = 0
DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING = 0

i = True
for line in arquivo:
    if i: # para pular a primeira linha
        i = False
        continue
    TOTAL_CHARGEABLE_UNITS = TOTAL_CHARGEABLE_UNITS + sum(line[14:18] + ...)
    DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING = DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING + sum(line[19:22] + ...)
arquivo.close()

arquivo = open("/dados/cdrs-roaming/resultado.txt", "w")
arquivo.writelines([TOTAL_CHARGEABLE_UNITS],[DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING])
arquivo.close
```

`TOTAL_CHARGEABLE_UNITS` e `DATA_VOLUME_OUTGOING` são os campos desejados nesse caso. Sou iniciante então não tive ideia de como criar essa soma. Alguma ideia?

Detalhe: acredito que eu deva converter esses campos/intervalos para `float`, mas não sei como fazer isso sem converter o arquivo inteiro.

Comment: Um negócio que pod te ajudar é, a partir de cada linha, criar um objeto de alto nível. Aí, com uma lista desses objetos você opera nas propriedades deles.  Não é  a melhor opção se é algo que você precisa fazer uma vez só e nunca mais olhar, mas, se esses dados são a base do um projeto maior, aí pode valer a pena
Dê uma olhada nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399778/como-extrair-as-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-um-arquivo-cnab-usando-python/400033#400033

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está percorrendo uma linha de cada vez, você terá apenas um valor a cada iteração, então não faz sentido usar `sum`. Apenas atualize as variáveis a cada iteração:

```
total_chargeable_units = 0
data_volume_outgoing = 0
with open('arq.txt') as arq:
    # se quiser pular a primeira linha
    next(arq)

    for linha in arq:
        total_chargeable_units += int(linha[13:18])
        data_volume_outgoing += int(linha[18:22])
```

Se quiser pular a primeira linha, basta chamar [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) no arquivo antes do `for` (e não usar o retorno para nada, assim a primeira linha será ignorada).

Eu converti os valores para `int` pois são números inteiros (não vi necessidade de usar `float`). E dentro do *loop* eu atualizo as somas. Repare que no *slice* eu coloquei `13:18` (pois a primeira posição é zero, então o décimo quarto caractere estará na posição 13, e a última posição - no caso, 18 - não é inclusa).

Depois, bastas escrever no arquivo de resultados:

```
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(f'{total_chargeable_units}\n{data_volume_outgoing}')
```

Tanto para ler quanto para escrever os arquivos eu usei `with`, que [garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) (assim você não precisa chamar `close`).

---

Se quiser, também pode generalizar, criando um dicionário com os nomes das variáveis e suas respectivas posições:

```
# guarda as posições inicial e final de cada variável
posicoes = {
    'total_chargeable_units': (13, 18),
    'data_volume_outgoing': (18, 22)
}

results = {}
with open('arq.txt') as arq:
    # se quiser pular a primeira linha
    next(arq)

    for linha in arq:
        # lê todas as posições e atualiza o valor das variáveis
        for variavel, (inicio, fim) in posicoes.items():
            try:
                results[variavel] = results.get(variavel, 0) + int(linha[inicio:fim])
            except ValueError:
                # se não tiver um número, mostra mensagem de erro
                print(f'Valor nas posições [{inicio}:{fim}] não é um número')

# grava tudo no arquivo
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as out:
    for qtd in results.values():
        out.write(f'{qtd}\n')
```

Também incluí uma validação, caso o arquivo não tenha um número nas referidas posições.

O resultado será outro dicionário, contendo os nomes das variáveis e seus respectivos totais.

Comment: Ajudou bastante! Ainda não alterei conforme sua segunda sugestão, mas a partir da sua ideia surgiu o código que deixei nas respostas

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvido a partir da resposta do colega **hkotsubo**:

Ajudou bastante! Ainda não alterei conforme sua segunda sugestão, mas a partir da sua ideia surgiu:

```
sequencia = ""
imsi = ""
msisdn = ""
operadora = ""
total_chargeable_units = 0
data_volume_outgoing = 0
gprs_apn_point = ""
with open('teste.GS3') as arq:
    # se quiser pular a primeira linha
    next(arq)

    for linha in arq:
        if imsi == linha[3:18]:
            msisdn = linha[188:209]
            operadora = linha[25:30]
            total_chargeable_units += int(linha[147:159])
            data_volume_outgoing += int(linha[159:171])
            gprs_apn_point = linha[237:300]
        else:
            sequencia = sequencia + imsi + ' ' + msisdn + ' ' + operadora + ' ' + str(total_chargeable_units) + ' ' + str(data_volume_outgoing) + ' ' + gprs_apn_point + '\n'
            imsi = linha[3:18]
            msisdn = linha[188:209]
            operadora = linha[25:30]
            total_chargeable_units = 0
            data_volume_outgoing = 0
            gprs_apn_point = linha[237:300]
            

    sequencia = sequencia + imsi + ' ' + msisdn + ' ' + operadora + ' ' + str(total_chargeable_units) + ' ' + str(data_volume_outgoing) + ' ' + gprs_apn_point + '\n'
            
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(sequencia)
```